# Where can I go to learn about decryption?

Tags: encryption

I understand the basics of encryption and decryption, but I don't know where to go to talk to people and learn more. Are there any forums or resources to look at to learn more?

For example, I was given two Hex strings and told that the second was modified, but originally a ~90% match of the first:

[3E 02 2D 06 7E 31 00 00 04 2A 7E 30 00 00 04 2A] 
and
[5A E1 78 F3 72 2C 90 D3 07 4A 10 41 49 4B 0D C4 F7 5D 9E 32 7C 01 F5]

I know the second one is encrypted because a simple statistical analysis shows a balanced distribution of values, but I don't know the process for trying to de-encrypt it.

Comment: Honestly, the best start for you might be to read the Wikipedia article on cryptography and purchase a college-level textbook on Cryptography. Look for texts like "Introduction to Cryptography" and "Applied Cryptography" because those may answer some of the questions you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two separate questions there:

> What communities can I go to to learn more about decryption?

Two quickly come to mind: [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/crypto) and [Cryptography Stack Exchange](https://crypto.stackexchange.com).

> Where do I go to find people to decrypt my specific problems?

You could try Stack Exchange, but there is also [a small community on Reddit called decoders](https://www.reddit.com/r/Decoders/) that will try to decode things if they think it's interesting.